# How to write and read images using GPU accelerated code in python?

Tags: python, io, gpu, cupy

I am a nuby to GPU coding. How to write and read images using GPU accelerated code in python? I have tried cupyimg, but the error says no such module named cupyimg. I tried cupyimg.scipy.misc etc. too. Is there a way, I can write my cupy array and read them. My image writing and reading is slower as I save more than 700000 images in device and then read them.

Comment: Are you performing any operations on the images because GPU acceleration may not always be faster than CPU-based image processing, especially for small images or simple operations.
If your only objective is to fasten the process, check how if you have more than one core on your system. if yes, try parallelizing the process using Python's `multiprocessing` library

Comment: Also if you're doing mathematical processing, a correctly setup numpy / pytorch can assist further in computation optimizations and parallelizing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to fasten the process. And if possible saving images using GPU and reading them later after operation, so that my device memory will not be stuck. Is there a way of doing this? otherwise I like the idea of multiprocessing.

Comment: multiprocessing is insanely slow with lots of overhead and little to no gain in my experience. Use Cython and `with nogil:` to allow multi-threaded access to your image buffer. be careful to not modify the buffer you read from as that is not thread-safe. I have successfully sped up image processing algorithms by about 100x using Cython

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing CuPy which can be solved using pip install package_name (check the official documentation for the library, it will contain the package name and how to install it).

With that being said, the best way to do GPU coding is to use Cuda (C++ code), or if you have an AMD graphics card use OpenGL/OpenCL to write your compute kernel; then you can compile it as a Python extension, and import it.

Comment: I have already installed CuPy. But, I cannot find any reading and writing packages in cupy. I tried CuPy._io, but it has nothing.

Comment: what do you mean by reading and writing packages? reading and writing to disk? gpu? display output?

Comment: I mean packages which can read and write images.